# Joining 2 tables with same id PDO

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am sorry this is not a high quality question and I know I am risking downvotes, but I am trying to learn as I go. I am currently working on a side project and stumbled into a situation I am not sure of.

I have two tables and need to call the data from both sharing the same id number (different names)

I will now attempt to give an example

Table 1

```
|  psid   |   idd   |
|  1      |    999  |
|  2      |    42   |
```

Table 2

```
|  aid     |      other      |
|  999     |    hello world  |
|  42      |    welcome      |
```

I am trying to link idd and aid whilst displaying all rows from table one

Example

- id = 1 / Title : hello world
- id = 2 / Title : welcome

I am not sure if this can be achieved with a single query to the database I have tried adding a second but it goes in a nonstop loop.

I have not done much searching as not sure what to search for.

Thanks and sorry

Comment: search for join in mysql

Comment: This should do it: `select tbl1.psid, tbl2.other from table_1 tbl1 left outer join table_2 tbl2 on tbl1.idd = tbl2.aid`

Comment: So far the only correct query is the one provided by @MonkeyZeus in the comment above.

Comment: *Roger that!* @MonkeyZeus

Comment: *Choo! Choo!* - @JayBlanchard - *N'est-ce pas Sam?*

Comment: *Est si Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cartesian Join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm)

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aff6a4/3)

```
select 
  table1.*, 
  table2.* 
from 
  table1, 
  table2 
where 
  table1.idd = table2.aid and 
  table1.idd = :id
```

Or [Left Join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aff6a4/4)

```
select
  t1.*,
  t2.*
from 
  table1 t1
left join
  table2 t2
on 
  t1.idd = t2.aid
where 
  t1.idd = :id
```

Comment: `id` should be `psid`

Comment: it's just meant to show the syntax. i'm sure his tables aren't called `table1` and `table2` either

Comment: Probably not, but if he missed that he might miss the syntax too.

Comment: My only other concern about your first query is that you will end up with a [Cartesian product](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) instead of just 2 rows.

Comment: @JayBlanchard can you be more specific? i don't understand why that's a reason to be "concerned" .. both queries produce the exact same result.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aff6a4/3, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aff6a4/4

Comment: Your first example returns 1 row, not 2. Same for your second example. Both, in this case, are not what the OP is asking for,

Comment: that is not specified anywhere in the question, but if that's what he needs all he has to do is remove the last/only "where" condition in each one. what does that have to do with cartesian joins?

Comment: Look at the example in the OP's post. Essentially 2 rows. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aff6a4/7 Cartesian product will become an issue when the data sets start growing. In the OP's example it isn't a problem because the data set is limited.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.psid, table2.other FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.idd = table2.aid
WHERE table1.idd= 'X' AND table2.aid = 'X'
```

this should JOIN the two tables together and by specifying the matching id's for each table in the WHERE clause should get the relevant information.

*EDIT* fixed SQL

Comment: You're only getting data from table 1.

Comment: Your join is also wrong, should be `idd` - `aid` according to what the OP is asking for. You're also returning everything where the OP asked for specific things.

Comment: Your join is still got the wrong column names. Table1 does not have an aid column.

Comment: Your select is wrong. `psid` from table1 and `other` from table2. Please, carefully read what the OP wrote.

Comment: You do not need a `WHERE` because you have an `ON`.

Comment: Elective. to say it's not needed misleads.

Comment: Not true @Haymaker. You would only use the `WHERE` clause to filter the results in this case. The `ON` statement matches all matchable rows with no further intervention required. Your `WHERE` clause would cause *this* case to return no results at all - which is certainly not what you want.

Comment: "call the data from both sharing the same id number" Under that statement it would not hurt to add.